# In the switch construction generate a lot of case statements

Tags: javascript

I have an educational task in which i have to write the function that generates 1000 case statements.

```
function f(x) { // function
    let y; // variable
    switch (x) { // switch
        for(let z; z < 1000; z++){ // loop
           y = case x:
               alert('True');
               break;
               return y
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to loop through case statements in the proper way

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? what's the educational task, like homework or an assignment from a teacher (if so, this is a really bad assignment)? is it just to generate 1000 case statements? or do you have some other requirements and this is the way you've thought of to solve the problem at hand? if you describe what the problem is we may be able to provide alternative solutions

Comment: It's not clear from your example why you need 1000 case statements. You are making the same test in each of them. Maybe you can edit the question with a more detailed example that shows what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: If you need "pooling", a `switch` statement is probably the wrong solution. Just use an `if (x > 0 && x < 1000) else` chain instead.

Comment: There need to 1000 case statements like: case 1:
            alert(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            alert(2);
            break

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For starters I do not think what you're doing is correct. You cannot add cases to a switch.
Tho maybe i'm misunderstanding who knows. but anyways,

The best way (*in my opinion*) to get 1000 cases that just do an alert would be

```
function f(x) { // function
    let text = `switch(x){`;
    for(let z =0;z<1000;z++){
        text+=`case ${z}:alert("true");break;`;
    }
    text+=`}`;
    eval(text);
}
f(100);//true
f(1001); //nothing
```

although this is quite stupid as this is quite a waste, the better way would be

```
function f(x){
    if(x>=0&&f<=1000) alert("true");
}
```

Also in the future you should try to deter from making such long for loops, those things can crash applications and browsers when running. Though now days most get along fine unless you do too many long ones.

Comment: IMHO even showing ‘eval()’ is a terrible idea. Also putting ‘alert()’ in a loop will drive you crazy in about 3 seconds.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I *fixed* his code. And warned him of everything. Eval has it's uses, and in this particular case it was required to fix it.

Comment: There really is no use case that requires `eval()`. Ever time someone says that `eval()` is required to get the code working, it's because the proposed solution is incorrect for the problem. Yes, `eval()` is needed to execute a string as JavaScript, but the *real* solution here is not to take that approach in the first place, thus making the use of `eval()` a moot point. The best solution to this problem is to reject the premise of the proposed solution in the first place. All that's needed here is a ternary statement in a loop.

Comment: Yes but I believe stack overflow is a place to answer these questions, Even if they are stupid.